# IntelliJで括弧の中身を入力した後エンターキーで自動でカーソルを括弧の外に移動させたい

Tags: intellij-idea

Eclipseでは例えば
　new int[n];
の[n]の部分を入力するとき、"["を入力すれば
　[!] (!がカーソル位置)
と括弧閉じまで補完され、サイズnを入力してエンターキーを押すと
　[n]!
と自動でカーソル位置を括弧の外に出してくれていました。

Intellijで同じ操作をすると、括弧閉じの補完までは同じですが、
　[n
　]!
とカーソル位置そのままで改行されてしまうので、毎回nと入力したあと→キーでカーソルを手動で移動させています。
この操作が煩わしいので省きたいのですが、ここの挙動をEclipseと同じようにする設定やショートカットはありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeyMap設定にある Editor Actions > Complete Current Statement がまさにそれでしょうか。

macOSでIDEA標準配列の場合<kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧shift</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>、Windowsの場合も同様に<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>のようです。

[image: https://gyazo.com/a1cff4185dfc1bce43efba00b52fb93f]

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。ストレスが減りそうです